# How to add GraphAware Library to project

Tags: php, eclipse, neo4j, phplib

I am creating a project in php and want to configure it with my Neo4j graph data. Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/Client.php';
use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client; 
use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;
$client = new GraphAware\Neo4j\Client('http://127.0.0.1:7474/');

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:password@127.0.0.1:7474')
->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@127.0.0.1:7474')
->build();
```

so you can see that the library I am trying to use in GraphAware. I cannot get this library to work as I do not have it. Can someone please let me know how I can get this library in my php project which I am creating in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, you use Composer to require it into your project.

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client#installation

```
composer require graphaware/neo4j-php-client:^4.0
```

Don't have composer? It's well worth installing, manages dependencies and autoloading, and all you need to do to get it working with any PHP project is to add this line pretty much at the start point of your script (index.php?)

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php`
```

Get Composer here https://getcomposer.org/

The lame non-composer way is just download the Zip from github and dump it in your project. But you'll need to require in all the classes you use!

Comment: For this do I need to get the 1.0.0-alpha4 composer?

Comment: No, use a stable version!

Comment: php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

Comment: php composer-setup.php, then php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Comment: Then follow this to get the composer command working from anywhere  https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: so when you say you 'need to require it in all the classes' is that by typing namespace GraphAware\Neo4j\Client; at he top of all the classes?

Comment: Are you using composer? add a `use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client;` rather than `namespace`. If not using composer, literally `require_once` the class files in

Comment: I can't install the composer because I don't have a command line php

Comment: so I just added it in from github

Comment: `require_once('/path/to/classfile.php'); use GraphAware\Blah; $x = new Blah();`

Comment: require_once ('C:/Users/se****/workspace/NetworkWeb/Config.php');

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder; $client = new GraphAware(); ?

Comment: or require_once ("C:\\Users\\sengjs5\\workspace\\NetworkWeb\\Config.php");?

Comment: `require_once /path/to/Client.php`! https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/blob/master/src/Client.php then `use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Client;`

Comment: tried this require_once ('C:/Users/sen****/workspace/NetworkWeb/Client.php');

Answer (score 0):

If your creating a PHP project in eclipse you can download the composer in eclipse form here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/composer-php-support

All you have to do is drag it into your running workspace. This will download all the libraries and dependencies for you. This is done by writing composer before the require statement.

The composer for eclipse is available in the following versions: Mars(4.5), Luna(4.4), Kepler(4.3). It is also supported by Windows, Mac and Linux/GTK

Before you download the composer the PHP development tools (PDT) are required.

Just to add. I have tried this in eclipse mars but it did not work for me so I tried it in Neo Oxygen and it worked!